# Why does creating a new tab give me 'TypeError: Expected Gtk.Widget, but got GObjectMeta'?

Tags: application-development, quickly, gtk3, pygi

```
def on_btn_new_subject_activate(self, widget):
    self.subjects.append_page(Gtk.TextView(), "Testing")
```

I am trying to create a new tab on a text area but I whenever the signal is called by the event (I click the button), this happens:

```
TypeError: Expected Gtk.Widget, but got GObjectMeta
```

I have also tried variations on this like "Gtk.GtkTextView()" and "GtkTextView()" with no success

What am I supposed to be using to get a text area in that tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must initialize Gtk.TextView() before use....
I was also facing same problem 2 days before.... 
Just check following code

```
        self.textview = Gtk.TextView()
        self.textbuffer = self.textview.get_buffer()
        self.textbuffer.set_text("This is some text inside of a Gtk.TextView. "
            + "Select text and click one of the buttons 'bold', 'italic', "
            + "or 'underline' to modify the text accordingly.")
        mywindows.add(self.textview)
```

Refer: http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/textview.html

Comment: I'm not getting the error, but it is not adding a page to the Notebook.

Comment: What is widget type of subject?

Comment: subjects is a Notebook widget

Comment: It is now called pages, but it is still the same thing.

Comment: This is my structure:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/154687/gtk-notebook-widget-in-a-notebook-widget

Comment: What not you add it directly from Glade it is very easy....

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3856/discussion-between-gau1991-and-njallam)